A way or test to understand if the differences detected by the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test have a location or shape origin
In the @Single Malt answer in Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic interpretation with large samples we read:

The Kolmogorov–Smirnov test is sensitive to differences in location
and shape, and this is one of its strengths, it is in a sense a
holistic measure rather than just taking a single metric such as
location. But this means that the K-S statistic (D_n) could give high
values for differences caused by location or shape and would not
distinguish between the two,

Is there a way or an additional (non-parametric) test - to perform after the KS test -, to distinguish if the differences detected by the KS test have a "location" or a "shape" origin/cause?

You could look at the empirical distributions and see what is going on... by the way I'm not sure whether by "shape" you mean any difference between two distributions that is not just location? Because there are very many possibilities how distributions can differ. And for sure distributions may differ in both location and shape.

Thanks.. By shape I mean any difference in the shape between the two distributions. Indeed, KS is sensitive "to the shape of a distribution
because it can detect differences everywhere along the scale (Darling, 1957)" (from: https://jaqm.ro/issues/volume-6,issue-3/pdfs/jaqm_vol6_issue3.pdf#page=5)

In some literature "shape" refers to the general distributional shape (basically all aspects other than location), but I have seen it used for more specific features of a distribution as well.

Thanks for your comment

I'd say that shape often (and I venture to assert correctly) excludes not just location but so also scale.

Thanks for your comment @NickCox

@Ommo are you primarily interested in one-sample or two sample tests?

Hi @Glen_b, in two-sample test...

Because both tests derive a single number from the Q-Q plot of the data, I would (warmly) suggest always examining that plot.  This simple consideration readily answers your question because you will see where and how much the distributions differ.  Essentially the only reason to apply a formal test, like KS or SW, is to make sure you aren't deceiving yourself concerning the differences that plausibly arise from chance mechanisms (and to demonstrate that to sceptics).

thanks for your comment @whuber

First 1 comment; why use KS, when a 2-sample Anderson-Darling would be a (much?) better test? KS only looks at the maximum difference between the 2 ECDF's; AD looks at the whole difference area between the 2 ECDF's.
Now, both KS and AD are "holistic" tests. Any difference, be it location, scale or shape, could give rise to a significant test result, and in the vast majority of the cases, a significant test result is due to "a little bit of all 3".
So moving to a possible way to asses why a KS (or AD) test was significant. You could first shift the location of one of the 2 samples; add a constant to 1 of them to make the means equal. You could also try with making the medians the same (I would try both; if the samples are very skewed, median may be better? Otherwise it probably will not matter). And run the KS (or AD) test again; did the test statistic increase/decrease? By how much? You now have a measure of the effect of location on the test statistic.
Now, separately, perform a scale transformation on one of the samples, to make the standard deviations equal, and repeat the test. You now have a measure of the effect of scale.
And now do both location/scale transformations together. Whatever is left is a measure of the effect of shape... (shape being "everything else that is not location or scale"). If after scale/transformation together, the test is still significant, then you can say that shape alone was different "enough" (but note that it does not mean that location/scale was not also significant!).
It can easily be that all 3 factors, by themselves, give rise to a significant test result. To check this, you could take 1 sample, and compare it against itself (not against the 2nd sample), but shifted/scaled as much as the 2nd sample was (now they have the exact same shape, but not location/scale; is the test still significant...).
I am not saying this is a rigorous approach, and that I could attach any confidence level to it, but if I wanted to explore why 2 ECDF's are significantly different, it would tell me. And I would preferrably use AD, than KS.

Thanks @jginestet! A very insightful answer!

Now, there is another issue: which answer to accept here? They are both amazing!

[This answer suggests an avenue of approach. It should not be seen as advocacy for doing this in practice, I haven't thought about it enough to be confident that it's practical or useful in general. However it might have some value as an exploratory tool perhaps.]
Because the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is based on the largest absolute difference in cdf, you can't really "split up" the measure and allocate the total contribution of different sources, like you might with an ANOVA, you can't partition a maximum like you can a sum of squares.
Perhaps with something like a Cramér-von Mises you could have more success in that sort of direction.
We can still do something though.
To begin, consider that you can shift the location along the axis to try to minmize the K-S statistic; if the distributions were otherwise the same, that shift to minimize could be regarded as the estimate of the shift that the "K-S" sees.
In a similar vein, if the shapes were the same you could try to find the place on a shift-scale surface that would minimize the K-S distance.
However, in general such optimization problems are not guaranteed to have a single local optimum; indeed the function we're optimizing is also not smooth. If the shapes differ I don't know that a single local optimum is even especially likely, so naive implementation of optimization algorithms might not always work especially well. It might also be the case that there's a ridge (or rather a valley) in the loss function in some situation, though I don't expect this is going to be particularly common.
However, if you did identify a global minimizer of location and scale, you could arguably look at the change in KS from the original to the shifted-and-scaled to (in some loose sense) represent how much of the  difference could not be attributed to location and scale. Of course it would have both difference due to population shape and noise in there (as well as the effect of optimizing the shift and scale on the value; it will be smaller than it should be if the population values had been used).
Will this work very well? I suspect that sometimes it won't, especially not if the shapes differ a lot (the concept of shape will be confounded with the shift and scale). But sometimes at least, it might be both feasible and perhaps somewhat informative.
I haven't tried this aside from some simple cases, so there may well be more issues than the ones I anticipate.
This doesn't leave you with a test, I think. Certainly you can't use KS tables with such shifted and scaled statistics (you'd need new tables if it works at all), and I don't think that this can be distribution-free any longer (any more than a Lilliefors approach is distribution-free).

Many thanks @glen_b !! Great tips on what to do!! :-)

Take care - I just added some warnings/caveats at the start and end of my answer.

Now that I know it's for the two sample case, I'll sleep on it and think about it some more.

I will! It is for sure a way worth to be explored!

Thanks! Yes, I should have written that I was referring to a two-sample test.. sorry
